# laravel sanctum won't create database table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

Currently I trying to make an API auth using laravel sanctum in every tutorial that I watched

while running `php artisan migrate` it created a new table with the name of **create_personal_access_token_table** but when I run `php artisan migrate` it says **Nothing to migrate**

Note:I have already created laravel auth and tables with bootstrap.

Laravel Version : 8.61.0

Answer (score 0):

Check your migration list. Is there migration that create "personal_access_tokens" table ?

Comment: No nothing is there even if i run ```php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Sanctum\SanctumServiceProvider"```

Comment: "sanctum" config file exists in config directory ?

Comment: YES it exists in config directory

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).